# How to implement actionscript matrix in java?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, matrix, transpose

I want to convert in actionscript matrix to java

```
import flash.geom.Matrix;  
var mat:Matrix=new Matrix();
```

I want to convert upper actionscript code in java code. Have any idea about this?

Comment: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

Comment: thanks but i solved problem by java as3 api for android from google code